# Need to disable "open , save , save as prompt" while opening pdf in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, adobe, internet-explorer-11

I have tried searching for an answer and it was said that, we need to do the following:
1. click on the file and click on save when prompted.
2. open IE11 ->tools->view downloads.
3. Right click on the pdf file and uncheck the checkbox for "Always ask before opening this type of file"

How ever in my system, I do not get this option for pdf, though I get this option for excel file(.xls). In another system where I need to remove this prompt, I do not get this option either for .pdf or .xls

Some extra information:

I have the adobe pdf reader add-on enabled in manage add-ons.

I tried merging the following into registry

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute{0002DF01-0000-0000- C000-000000000046}]
"AcroExch.Document.DC"=hex(0):

as I get .pdf=AcroExch.Document.DC when I type assoc.pdf into cmd

So my question would be

1.how to get this option on right clicking a file in IE11->tools->view downloads

2. Is there any other way to disable the prompt while opening pdf in IE11

Answer (score 1):

I found that this happened to me because the Windows Explorer file type association had been changed to use IE as the default program.  To fix, right-click on any .pdf file in Windows Explorer, select "open with", Choose Another App, and then reset the default to Adobe Reader or your preferred app.

[image]

Comment: I do not have the setup anymore to check if it works. Thanks for an answer though. Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

2 solution.

Try to use javascript

```
Function(){
window.open("c:\\ .....  \\filename");
}
```

Or

```
<a href="fileroute" target="_blank">  </a>
```